# How can I select with a datetime WHERE clause in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I need to select just less than datetime, I do something like this:

```
  SELECT StackerReplacedEventID, Occured 
  FROM StackerReplacedEvent 
  WHERE Occured<CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Jul 11 2011 03:50PM', 120)
```

but I get an error.  I've also tried this way:

```
WHERE Occured<'Jul 11 2011 03:50PM'
```

Comment: what type of data is Occured, is it datetime?

Comment: As I mentioned below - I've got a timestamp string from MSSQL this way 'Jul 11 2011 03:50PM' and that is why I need to convert this string in string compatible to MSSQL. the error is "convertion error of date or time from symbol string"

Comment: So, where is the real decision I don't need to set ISO strings by hands lol or make convertion with the same error alertion?

Comment: @zeusakm: It is still not clear from your response **what is data type of `Occured`**. Is it `datetime` or is it `char`/`varchar`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an ISO date format instead of a regional and/or language-specific one.

```
WHERE Occured < '2011-07-11T15:50:00';
```

Now that we know the language settings are Russian (after 15 tries), maybe we can do some brute force work here.

```
WHERE Occured < CONVERT(DATETIME, 
    REPLACE(N'Jul 11 2011 03:50PM', N'Jul', N'июл'), 100)
```

Note that the N prefixes are important!

So in reality since you will have data representing all 12 months, it will probably be something like:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
original_column,N'Jan', N'янв')
,N'Feb',    N'фев')
,N'Mar',    N'мар')
,N'Apr',    N'апр')
,N'May',    N'май')
,N'Jun',    N'июн')
,N'Jul',    N'июл')
,N'Aug',    N'авг')
,N'Sep',    N'сен')
,N'Oct',    N'окт')
,N'Nov',    N'ноя')
,N'Dec',    N'дек')
```

This is awful, though. Please consider choosing the right data type for this data.

Now do you see why understanding what language you were using, instead of "helpfully" translating the error message, was important?

Comment: the problem is that this type of timestampt stores in MSSQL - how to convert this type to ISO on SQL in MSSQL?

Comment: What do you mean, it is stored this way as a string in SQL Server? Why? Anyway, shouldn't be a problem, unless your regional settings/collation/language are not the default. Do you get an error message in a language other than English?

Comment: I've got a timestamp string from MSSQL this way 'Jul 11 2011 03:50PM' and that is why I need to convert this string in string compatible to MSSQL. the error is "convertion error of date or time from symbol string"

Comment: That is not the error message. Can you copy and paste the EXACT error message?

Comment: Don't U steel understand I need the auto-converter, I can't make the convertion my self on hands like U deed it is lame dude. Give me the real convertion method in MSSQL. An error I've translated from SQL Manager from Russian into English, but it doesn`t matter in Your case.

Comment: Oh, it's Russian! Thank you for finally revealing this mysterious information! Do you think the problem might be that the Russian language has no idea what Jul is? Why aren't you storing date/time data as datetime or smalldatetime? Also calling people trying to help you "lame" isn't going to win you many friends here.

Comment: I don't see any point here except bla bla bla, also I didn't call U lame, if U were a little bit attentive, I told that Your hand convertion method is lame =) Russian here is not the point too - what are U talking about? I'm storing datetime in DateTimeStamp:datetime actual format and why don't U try just solve it rather then bla bla bla. PS I don't search for freands here - only partners and professionals.

Comment: That is not possible. You cannot store a datetime value as 'Jul bla bla'. Why are people so inappreciative of others trying to go out of their way to help them solve their problems and correct their horrible choices? Also, by "friends" I didn't mean buddy buddy let's go hang out at the mall, I meant people who are willing to help you work through your problems.

Comment: Wow, you accepted my answer even though I was being lame, doing a lot of bla bla bla, not trying to solve the problem, and wondering about the language being used for no reason? Interesting. How do you say apology in Russian?

Comment: You've got me on my shoulders dude U are cool in MSSQL as minimum - sorry for greasy language and words. So the next Q is how could I compare for example simply with timestamp convertion of a MSSQL TIMESTAMP than do not write things like 'июл' - You are learning Russian already =)

Comment: You can't. Store your data as DATETIME or SMALLDATETIME instead of storing regional English month names and expecting magic translation to Russian.

Comment: In Russian apology is Извиняюсь =) I'm not only accepted Your answer, but give U a point up either.

Answer (score 0):

`CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Jul 11 2011 03:50PM')` it's working for me